# Disable or restrict azure IOT device after provisioning with DPS

Tags: java, azure, iot

I have created one Device provision service. Then I have created enrollment group to the provision of a device to IOT Hub. It's working fine and the device is also able to provision. 
By default, Device will enable for connection to IOT Hub after provision.

Question: Now if I want that when the device will provision it will be in disable state. Is it possible or another way to do the same?

Comment: Hi,Did you find any workaround for this?